# Why do non-constructible numbers imply the impossibility of geometric constructions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

The question may seem a bit stupid at a first glance, but let me explain.

A **constructible number** is constructed by a sequence of compass and straightedge constructions that always begin with two points $0$ and $1$.

For example, it is usually proved that squaring the circle by compass and straightedge is impossible because $\sqrt{\pi}$ is not a constructible number. While I understand that given two points $0,1$, one cannot construct the number $\sqrt{\pi}$ by compass and straightedge, I don't understand why given a circle, one cannot construct a square with the circle's area by compass and straightedge.

The "starting configurations" are given "in intrinsic form", without reference to a particular coordinate system and it is not always possible to choose a coordinate system such that the starting configurations are definable from points with constructible coordinates.

So why do non-constructible numbers imply the impossibility of geometric constructions?

Comment: Can you please edit your post to give a more enlightning example? The one of squaring the circle is not, because that problem boils down to squaring the [*unit* circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).

Comment: @AnneBauval Why does squaring of an arbitrary circle boil down to squaring the unit circle? This is exactly the thing I don't understand.

Comment: Choose any [dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(affine_geometry)) mapping one circle to the other one, and it will map your square solution for one circle to a square solution for the other one.

Comment: Why do you say "it is not always possible to choose a coordinate system such that the starting configurations are definable from points with constructible coordinates"?  If you have a circle, you can always choose coordinates to make it the unit circle centered at the origin.